# Creating RDLC report in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-webapi, rdlc

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project and have to create RDLC report & I have installed these extensions for the the reporting as shown below.

I cannot create the RDLC report from new item option popup window.

Please help me to sort this issue.

[image: Installed]

[image: new item list]

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE 2024-04-05**

We may facing some issue, like `Compiler executable file C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v8.0.0\vbc.exe cannot be found`.

*Here is the workaround.*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1467901/integrating-rdlc-reports-in-blazor-web-apps

---

After testing, I found we can't find .rdlc item in .net core peoject by using VS2022.

As the workaround, we can create the .rdlc file in .net application, then copy it to our .net core project.

[**Related Link:** Create RDLC Report in ASP.NET Core application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnAVcemvmyo)